# How to Save and Load all Xaml Code of my Program C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There are two Buttons, one for save and one for load (WPF)

I'd like to save all the XAML Code of the Program
, and be able to load it back to its saved State

The Canvas i want to save has a lot of objects in it and don't like to hardcode everything.

Is there a way to do this for all cases and not only for this one?

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="test" Height="552" Width="1143">
    <Canvas Name="cs">
        <Canvas Name="csmain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="523" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1129">
            <TextBox Name="tbx" Height="23" Canvas.Left="173" Text="" Canvas.Top="10" Width="159" />
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

void save(string path)
{
???
}
void load(string path)
{
???
}

Comment: XAML is a description of how to display the form, you already have that in the source code.  I think you are trying to 'make things easier, by making things harder'.  You can just serialise your viewmodel (you do have one of those, right?)

Comment: @Neil ViewModel is not mandatory way of using WPF.

Comment: @TomášFilip It certainly is not. However, using some separation of your data and display (like using a ViewModel) is a good practice, and it becomes *especially*  clear in cases like this one (IMO). If all the logic of the view adds manually XAML elements in the UI tree, this will lead to more and more spaghetti-code with every new feature (save, load, etc...) added. And moreover, since you're right the viewmodel it's not mandatory, the question at the end of Neil's comment is meaningful, and important to answer, as this will probably drive any potential answer to add details on this regard

Comment: @MusicGrotesqueTV: Could you please add some context to understand the structure of your program? Do you use MVVM pattern, with a ViewModel? How is your "XAML code" that you want to save changed during execution?